# C# DirectX Draw lines using DrawUserPrimitives works fine but DrawPrimitives don't work

Tags: c#, drawing, directx, lines

I've got problem with DirectX in C#. I want to draw some lines. Firstly I've done it with DrawUserPrimitives and all is fine. But then I switched to vertexBuffer because I want to make rotations and other camera action. And I can't see nothing in the window.

There is part of code that fills vertexBuffer and draw verts on a plane.

```
vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(typeof(CustomVertex.PositionColored), 
   8 * (CurrentPanel.ElementsCount() + 1), m_device, Usage.None,
   CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format, Pool.Default);
CustomVertex.PositionColored[] verts =
   (CustomVertex.PositionColored[])vertexBuffer.Lock(0, 0);
//this function returns array of verts based on given points.
verts = CurrentPanel.GetLines(); 
vertexBuffer.Unlock();
m_device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255).ToArgb(), 1.0f, 0);
m_device.BeginScene(); //m_device is my DirectX.Device
SetupViewport(); //Set all of matrixes...
m_device.SetStreamSource(0, vertexBuffer, 0);
m_device.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format;
//m_device.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineList, CurrentPanel.ElementsCount() * 4, verts); // <- WHEN I USE THIS ALL IS OK
m_device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineList, 0, 4*(CurrentPanel.ElementsCount()+1)); //<-DO NOT WORK
m_device.EndScene();
m_device.Present();
```

I would like to add that this code is based on Microsoft DirectX samples.

Comment: How do you determine that it doesn't work? Do you get an error or do the primitives simply not appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not write the vertices to the VertexBuffer.

You created a variable named `verts` and used it to reference the Array that is returned from the `Lock` method, then you replaced the array referenced by `verts` to be the return value from `CurrentPanel.GetLines()`.
But you didn't actually write anything to the VertexBuffer.

Comment: Yep, thats was the problem. Thanks a lot :)
Only one more question: Is it possible to put data directly in vertexBuffer, because now I put data from Function CurrentPanel.GetLines() into temporary table and then make loop to rewrite data from temp to verts.

Comment: You can try to use the `SetData` method. Another solution might be changing `CurrentPanel.GetLines()` and have it create and fill the vertex buffer when it creates the lines.